# Expo network response Timed Out, Can't run Expo app on android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run My react-native application, I'm running it on android emulator and my phone HUAWEI Y3II and same thing happens.
I was working on it fine a few days ago but suddenly this error keeps coming up:
`Could not load exp://*myip*:19000 network response timed out`

[image]

[image]
And the terminal Log shows:

```
Fetching the user profile failed
connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443
aTrying to open the project on Android...
Opening on Android device
```

I tried setting the environment variable REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME to my ip address,
I tried turning off the firewall,
I ensured that the ports are allowed in the firewall,
I tried changing my network from public to private.
Here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "^35.0.0",
        "react": "16.8.3",
        "react-dom": "16.8.3",
        "react-native": "file:../../../../Users/RiggedToBlow/Downloads/Compressed/react-native-sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
        "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
        "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

I really need to work on this please help

Comment: click on "View Error logs" of Errors screen in emulator

Comment: This message Appears:
Uncaught Error:java.net.SocketTimeOutException:timeout

Comment: Try clicking the reload icon (the one to the right, not the house). This was all I needed to do. I wouldn't expect that it *always* works, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just go to wifi setting
Click on your WIFI name
And enable Make this pc discoverable
Good luck

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks. I wasted about 2 hours looking up another post on stackoverflow for the same problem where it said to set an environment variable in command window i.e. `set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.124` to the wifi IPV4 address obtained from ipconfig command, but it didn't work. This solution you recommended worked.

Comment: how to do in mac?

Answer (score 6):

1. make sure that your mobile and computer is connected to the same WIFI network
2. if your computer is connected to your mobile hotspot then try running the app using`expo start --tunnel` command
   if it still doesn't solve the issue then
3. change your WIFI to private and turn off the firewall for private network.

Comment: is there any solution that my friend can run an app on his device because we both have different connection at that time??

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you need to change your WiFi settings from public to private especially if you have the firewall settings turned on in Windows 10. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: For me, changing the network profile to private was enough. This is good because you should avoid disabling the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Make your PC discoverable. Go to the wifi list on the bottom right in windows > click "properties" > toggle the "Network Profile" setting to "Private". Should solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

simply change your wifi settings to private and turn off the firewall too.

Comment: I never had the issue and strangely now, but what you suggested really helped.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your wifi name >properties > make the network private
then in network protection& firewall >> turn off firewall protection of private network

this worked fine with me

Answer (score 0):

Go to your windows firewall settings and set new inbound rule for port 19000.

Answer (score 0):

Expo may give you a QR code that your Android can't reach.

After you check the firewall port 19000, and check that Android is on the same WiFi network as your dev machine, check if the url is `192.168.10.xxx` whereas your phone is on `192.168.1.xxx`. Find the IP address of your dev machine on the `192.168.1` subnet (same subnet as the Android device). Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in my Ubuntu device by allowing `19000/tcp` in my firewall

1- `sudo ufw allow 19000/tcp`

2- `sudo ufw disable`

3- `sudo ufw enable`

4- And then go to your project files and run `npm start`

That works well with me on Ubuntu,

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me.
Set your WIFI to private and disable the firewall for a private network.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).