# Why Doesn't Expo Android Emulator Show App?

Tags: android, react-native, command-line, android-emulator, expo

I'm new to Expo and I'm trying to run a React Native app using `yarn android`. (The app is just the basic one created using `expo init my-project`.) However, while the command launches the emulator just fine, all I ever see is the emulated device --- the app never appears. If I close the emulator after waiting a long time, the terminal says that the emulator closed before it finished loading.

This is what the terminal shows right before the emulator launches:

[image]

Here is what the emulator looks like once it launches:

[image]

Here is what terminal says if I finally just close the emulator:

[image]

And here is what it looks like if I let the emulator run until it times out trying to load the app:

[image]

Do you have any idea why the app never loads and how to get it to do so? If I run `yarn web`, the app loads in browser fine, so I know it's not an issue with the app itself.

Comment: As a note, I also tried "expo run:android" but I get the same behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few steps missing from the Expo instructions online / in their terminal output. You can't immediately jump into `yarn android` after creating a project unless you have met the following condition:

- The `Expo Go` app is installed on your emulator/simulator

If you don't have the app installed, the command `yarn android` (which calls `expo start --android` as the real command) will fail with a timed out error.

You can install `Expo Go` via the command line (as long as you're cd'd into your project) using the command:

- `expo client:install:android`   [for Android]
- `expo client:install:ios`   [for iOS]

*However*, that command will also fail (with a timed out error) unless you've already gone into your emulator/simulator and logged into your Play Store / App Store.

So if you're trying to run Expo on a new emulator / one that's never run it before, your steps must be:

1. Open your emulator. Navigate to its Play/App Store and log into your account
2. Open Terminal. Create an Expo project using `expo init my_project_name`
3. `cd` into your project
4. Install Expo Go using the command `expo client:install:android` or `expo client:install:ios`
5. Run your app using `yarn android` or `yarn ios` (or `expo start --android` or `expo start --ios` if you don't have yarn installed)

Do that and everything should work!

Note: One other error I've seen pop up after all this happens is a `Network Response Timed Out` in the emulator itself when it's trying to load the app. If you get that error after step 5, do:

6. Cancel out of your current run attempt by using `Ctrl+C`
7. Append `--tunnel` to your original run command and try again
   (e.g. `yarn android --tunnel`). (Keep an eye on the Terminal, you may see something akin to the following `The package @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0 is required to use tunnels, would you like to install it globally?` Just type `yes` or hit `Enter` if "yes" is already present.) See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382437/expo-network-response-timed-out-cant-run-expo-app-on-android-emulator) for more information about the `--tunnel` solution and a couple of alternatives (the issue most likely arising due to firewall behavior)

Answer (score 1):

- execute:

```
expo start
```

that generate a QR code

- download ExpoGo on the device from Play Store.   Is necessary play store android emulator version and google account for using play store.
- scan QR code and the app is loaded on the device or click open on android device in the web page that is open after execute expo start.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying I need to install ExpoGo on my computer's android emulator, and then run the app by navigating to it on the emulator's browser? That doesn't seem like it should be necessary from any documentation I've read. It should be fine to just use 'yarn android'. Otherwise, what's the point of the command?